# BST in C - element deletion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

EDIT: The issue did not lie exactly where I initially assumed. The question asked and the code within it are only partially relevant to the real issue. See my accepted answer.

I am working on an assignment where I keep a BST of users, which is ordered alphabetically based on their names.

The delete function uses inorder traversal to find a user based on his name and then removes him from the tree.

The assignment is tested in a school system and I do not know what the input is but only the tests which use element deletion fail, because I return wrong names once the system asks for the tree contents again. I have been on this for hours and I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Relevant code:

```
//User struct
struct user{
  char name[100];
  int height;
  struct user* left;
  struct user* right;
};


//finds the leftmost child of a node
struct user* minUser(struct user* user)
{
    struct user* min = user;
    while (min->left != NULL)
        min = min->left;
    return min;
}


//recursive delete function 
struct user* delete(struct user *root, char *name){
  if (root == NULL)
    return NULL;
  int compare = strcmp(name,root->name);
  if (compare<0){
    root->left = delete(root->left,name);
  }
  else if (compare>0){
   root->right = delete(root->right,name); 
  }
  else {
    //If node has only one child
    if (root->left == NULL){
      struct user* temp = root->right;
      free(root);
      return temp;
    } else if (root->right == NULL){
      struct user* temp = root->left;
      free(root);
      return temp;
    }
    //If node has both children. I suspect the error to be here most likely
    struct user* temp = minUser(root->right);

    strcpy(root->name, temp->name);
    //root->height = temp->height;
    root->right = delete(root->right, strdup(temp->name));
  }
  return root;
}
```

Comment: It (probably) doesn't cause your error, but you do leak memory by discarding the pointers to the strings you allocate dynamically via `strdup()`.

Comment: Probably time to write some simple test code yourself and step through the running tests with a debugger and see what works.

Comment: Is there any chance that your deletion code assumes a different tree order than your insertion and search code does?  It would still be correct in itself if it swapped the roles of the left and right children, but it would not work on trees populated via an insertion function that used the opposite order.

Comment: @this, I considered that, but I convinced myself that the OP's code will indeed work in the presence of duplicates.  That is, when asked to delete a name from a tree containing dupes, it will return the root node of a valid BST containing one fewer instance of that name.  What do you see that would prevent it from doing so?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I checked and it doesn't seem to. My assumption here could be faulty and the problem could lie ina completely different part of the progamme as it is larger than just getting users from the tree, but I am 80% sure the problem is here. There is a hash map of pages and the tree represents users that liked the previous page. The previous test tested all the other features with with 1000 pages, 1000 users, and 1000x (20 like, 50 get)- hence why I assume the problem lies here.

Comment: If you can't be 100% positive that the error is here (and I, myself, am unconvinced) then both you and we will benefit from minimal code with which an error can be reproduced.  Please present an MCVE.

Comment: The delete function is deleting correctly. You are leaking memory with strdup. Your question cannot be answered, because there is no information how and what are those tests doing, and where is the discrepancy.

Comment: The `delete` function, which you should name differently for obvious reasons of portability, seems correct, except it does not update the `height` fields at all and leaks memory.   Do you update te BST root at the calling site:  `myroot = delete(myroot, name);` ?

Comment: You do not need the `strdup` at all: just change the last statement to `root->right = delete(root->right, root->name);`

Comment: @chqrlie Yes I do. The memory leak I have removed now, but with all of that being said and your comments I am now convinced that the problem has to lie somewhere else. Thank you for your help guys. I will have to do this on my own. I cannot really produce an MCVE at the moment because of time constraints. What is the stackover code? Should I delete the question now?

Comment: I found the problem... it was in the struct definition with char name[100];... Somehow when I changed that to a char *name and allocated it when inserting the new users it passed the tests. It must have somehow matched with the test input or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem did not lie where I initially assumed. It was in the struct definition which contained char name[100];. When I changed that to a pointer char *name and dynamically allocated memory to it when inserting the new users it passed the tests.

Sorry for the confusion.